# Why my Dojo.xhrGet calling the error Call Back method

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dojo

While executing this below Dojo code the call back mehod is calling the onFailure.
But if i will do

```
console.warn("Resp Code:"+ioargs.xhr.status);
```

It gives me 200 as status  code why this is happening,it should go to the load but it is calling the error.

```
dojo.xhrGet({ preventCache : "true",
        url : path,
        sync:true,
        load : onSuccess,
        error : onFailure,
        handleAs : "json"
    });
```

Comment: Post the `onSuccess` method.  That method could be throwing an exception, which is forcing it down to the `onFailure` call

Comment: it is having nothing but console.warn("In Response") just to track my call is under load method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely, since you've told the request to handle the response as json, the response you are getting back is not actually json, which can generate the error. From the Live Docs @ dojotoolkit.org:

> This parameter specifies how to handle the data returned from the server. It usually takes values of 'text', 'xml', or 'json'. What those values do is instruct it to try and hand the data to the asynchronous callback functions in that format. Naturally if you specify a format that doesn't match what the server sends you will likely get an error.

Make sure the response is sending back valid JSON and the server is sending it as the application/json content-type, otherwise set your handleAs to text.